# Google AMP Wordpress plugin: only working on some blog posts

Tags: wordpress

I installed the official Wordpress AMP plugin on the blog running the latest version of WP and noticed that while for some of the older posts AMP version gets generated just fine, for newer posts it just doesn't work. When I try to reach amp version by adding /amp to the URL, the page only gets reloaded to the original. The original posts that do not work also do not include link rel="amphtml" to the amp version in the source.

At first I thought that Yoast SEO plugin is causing problems with URL rewrites and I also installed Glue for Yoast and AMP to fix the compatibility, but the problem remains. I could not find a pattern that differs the posts that work from the ones that do not, only that the working posts are older.

An example of a post with working AMP: [Here](https://gizzmo.si/blog/test-xiaomi-yi-action-cam/amp)

An example of a post with non-working AMP: [Here](https://gizzmo.si/blog/instagram-stories/)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked amp version of your site and it seems that both URLs are working fine. Are you still facing the issue?, then you may try using other [amp plugins](https://talktopoint.com/wordpress-amp-and-instant-articles/) to see if the problem exist or not.

AMP is quite new in the market so there are can be lot of possibilities for this problem.